# I want to particular data from my image or pdf

Tags: ocr, invoice

I want to particular data from my image or pdf. For example I have **invoice bill** in scan document so i just want to **extract** **invoice number**. I am already used **Tesseract OCR, Apache Tika OCR, Aspose OCR** so please suggest me step to get particular data. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get/extract some specific contents from a portion of the image by using [custom recognition blocks](https://docs.aspose.com/display/ocrnet/Formatting+and+Manipulating+OCR#FormattingandManipulatingOCR-AddingUserDefinedRecognitionBlocks). Please note, the above mentioned solution is useful in scenario when you have documents/images following the similar structure, that is; the contents to be scanned are always on the same location for each image.

Furthermore you can perform OCR operation on a PDF file using Aspose.OCR in combination with Aspose.Pdf. Visit the link [Performing OCR on PDF Documents](https://docs.aspose.com/display/ocrnet/Performing+OCR+on+PDF+Documents) for details.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at using ABBYY FlexiCapture? That function is one of the primary aspects of what it does. In using products like FlexiCapture the issue becomes whether your document is of fixed or semi-structured design. For documents like invoices the answer is almost always semi-structured because the information moves around on the page. Also, there are usually many different layouts of invoices. ABBYY solved that challenge through their FlexiCapture for Invoice product.

As an alternative, if you just needed to extract something like an invoice number in a region there are ways in lower priced products like ABBYY Recognition Server in which you could use what they call an area template, or you could extract all of the OCR text and develop an application to apply a regular expression to locate the field value adjacent to the field label. Problems can arise when the field label and the field value do not fall in proximity to each other in the OCR result text. This can happen when after the line break of the field labels ("invoice no" or "invoice #") there is another value immediately following on the first position of the next line. Then the OCR text could become something like "Invoice No.  Bob's Bargain Barn 66422."  The Regex could look for the value immediately following the search phrase "Invoice No." then produce a result for the adjacent text "Bob's Bargain Barn."  Worse, often times the label text and invoice number will be within a table, complicating matters as some OCR engines would ignore it altogether (not Recognition Server though). It is for these reasons we researched FlexiCapture because it eliminated fancy coding required for data extraction. It is expensive but worth it. 
Disclosure, we are an ABBYY Partner.